# How to remove everything after the first space for each line in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, substring

I have a file with a list of commands as follows:

```
vi ../../www_com/pub/index.html
vi www/pub/index.html
vi yum.conf
watch --interval=0.5 'ss -trnp'
watch ll
watch ls -la
watch ls -lat
watch ls -lat cron
watch ls -lat /cron
wbinfo --alldomains
```

How can i go through the file and remove everything after the first space on every line to be left with:

```
vi
vi
vi
watch
watch
watch
watch
watch
watch
wbinfo
```

Comment: `awk '{print $1}' file`?

Comment: @Inian That empty line seems to have disappeared so I'd `'$1!=""{print $1}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
cut -f1 -d' ' filename
```

It *shows the first column, using a space as the delimiter*.